# Failed to Implement the Distance versus Angle Signature for Object Representation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm working on image representation using distance versus angle signature. There is no problem when I compute the object reference signature. But when I compare it with same object which was rotated or scaled, it never result in the same or even similiar signature. I'm sure there are some mistakes in the distance measurement or in the signature normalization, but I couldn't find it.

Here are my images:

cartridge.png

[image: cartridge.png]

cartridge-rotate.png

[image: cartridge-rotate.png]

cartridge-scale.png

[image: cartridge-scale.png]

Signatures:

cartridge.png: [100, 0, 2, 4, 9, 17, 22, 20, 19, 19, 21, 27, 25, 21, 17, 13, 11, 10, 11, 12, 16, 21, 19, 17, 16, 12, 11, 14, 16, 18, 24, 30, 24, 20, 19, 9]

cartridge-rotate.png: [100, 5, 5, 82, 6, 6, 8, 11, 9, 8, 7, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 10, 9, 7, 83, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 7, 83]

cartridge-scale.png: [100, 0, 5, 13, 24, 34, 31, 30, 31, 34, 44, 44, 34, 26, 21, 17, 16, 18, 21, 26, 34, 30, 26, 25, 18, 18, 19, 22, 27, 37, 46, 39, 33, 29, 16, 94]

And here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import cv2 as cv
import timeit as exe


def getCentroid(img):
   # Find object centroid

   row, col = img.shape

   xVal = 0
   yVal = 0
   n = 0.0

   for x in range(0,row):
      for y in range(0,col):
         if (img[x,y] == 255):
            xVal += x
            yVal += y
            n += 1.0

   xVal /= n
   yVal /= n

   return [np.int64(np.round(xVal)),np.int64(np.round(yVal))]


def getDistanceAngle(img, centroid, alpha):
   # Compute distance from centroid to boundary with specified angle

   row, col = img.shape

   xVal = np.float64(centroid[0])
   yVal = np.float64(centroid[1])
   x1 = centroid[0]
   y1 = centroid[1]

   x2 = x1
   y2 = y1

   distance = 0.0

   r = 0
   while (((xVal >= 0 and xVal < row) and (yVal >=0 and yVal < col)) and (img[np.int64(xVal),np.int64(yVal)] == 0)):
      x2 = np.int64(xVal)
      y2 = np.int64(yVal)

      xVal = x1 + r * (np.cos(np.deg2rad(alpha)))
      yVal = y1 + r * (np.sin(np.deg2rad(alpha)))
      r += 1

   # Euclidean distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)
   distance = np.sqrt(np.power(x2 - x1, 2) + np.power(y2 - y1, 2))
   return distance


def getSignature(img, centroid, delta):
   # Get signature of object

   alpha = 0.0
   signature = []

   while (alpha < 360.0):
      signature.append(getDistanceAngle(img, centroid, alpha))
      alpha += delta

   return signature


def normalization(signature, th):
   # Perform normalization to object signature
   # Deal with object rotation and scaling

   # Deal with object rotation
   # Find maximum value in signature
   # Split and merge signature
   # Maximum value moved to the first place
   maxIdx = np.argmax(signature)
   sortSig = signature[maxIdx:]
   sortSig.extend(signature[0:maxIdx])

   # Deal with object scaling
   # Find maximum and minimum value
   # Rescale each value to the maximum range (th -> threshold)
   normSig = []
   maxSig = np.float64(np.max(signature))
   minSig = np.float64(np.min(signature))

   for s in sortSig:
      distTemp = ((s - minSig) / (maxSig - minSig)) * th
      distance = np.int64(np.round(distTemp))
      normSig.append(distance)

   return normSig


def verifySignature(sigOri, sigList, th):
   # Compare original signature with other signatures

   length = len(sigOri)
   rateList = []
   accList = []

   for sig in sigList:
      sim = 0.0
      for i in range(0,length):
         if (sigOri[i] == sig[i]):
            sim += 1.0
      rate = sim / length * 100.0
      rateList.append(rate)
      if (100.0 - rate <= th):
         accList.append(True)
      else:
         accList.append(False)

   return [rateList, accList]


def main():
   # Main functon

   img = []
   img.append(cv.imread("C:/Users/Kadek/Documents/Python/OpenCV/test/boundary/cartridge.png",0))
   img.append(cv.imread("C:/Users/Kadek/Documents/Python/OpenCV/test/boundary/cartridge-rotate.png",0))
   img.append(cv.imread("C:/Users/Kadek/Documents/Python/OpenCV/test/boundary/cartridge-scale.png",0))

   centroid = []
   signature = []
   normalized = []

   for i in range(0,3):
      centroid.append(getCentroid(img[i]))
      signature.append(getSignature(img[i], centroid[i], 10.0))
      normalized.append(normalization(signature[i], 100.0))
      print(normalized[i])
      img[i][centroid[i][0],centroid[i][1]] = 100

   verification = verifySignature(normalized[0], [normalized[1],normalized[2]], 8.5)
   print(verification[0],verification[1])

   plt.imshow(img[2], cmap = cm.Greys_r)


start = exe.default_timer()
main()
end = exe.default_timer()
exeTime = end - start
print(exeTime)
```

Comment: Is there a special reason to use this distance-vs-angle signature? You'll have to put a significant effort to make it rotation and index-shift invariant. You might want to consider Fourier shape descriptors (FDs) to easily address these issues. See this [link](http://www.isy.liu.se/cvl/edu/TSBB08/lectures/DBgrkX1.pdf) I found [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/95105/fourier-descriptor-implementation-using-opencv/) for a very nice explanation of FDs.

Comment: @dhanushka Yes, i know that distance vs angle signature is not one of the best method. There is only one reason why i should use it: assignment LoL.